# How to change default framebuffer for Android?

Tags: android, default, framebuffer

i'm porting android to an overo gumstix. thus it seems the the omapfb driver has some problems on that platform. it doesn't matter at all, because i want to use udlfb (a driver for usb displays) anyway.

till today, i wasn't able to figure out how i can define udlfb as default framebuffer.
tried `make menuconfig` and select udlfb there, but no changes when booting the fresh compiled kernel. omapfb still wants to come up.

- so my final question: how do i define
  the default framebuffer driver for an
  android kernel?

thank you for any suggestions to this :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to disable omapfb in your kernel. In make menuconfig:

```
-> Device Drivers
 -> Graphics support
  -> OMAP2/3 Display Subsystem support (EXPERIMENTAL)
```

Disable the last option.

Also, be sure that udlfb is enabled by default (ie not in module).

Comment: i tried this already. my image still loads the omapfb driver.

do i have to make first `make clean` or is it enough to just rebuild the kernel with the new configuration?

Comment: ok, looked deeper into the make-scripts and explored that the guys i got the android-source from have overwritten the default .config-location with some specific file path.
modified now that file and try now to rebuild...

Comment: after using the right config, my driver was installed corectly. unfortunatly it seems that i have now some other problems...

after initializing the framebuffer, i get mysterious characters in my console (which looks like raw data or something) ... probably theres something else wrong now ;)